# Wix Installer TARGETDIR INSTALLDIR set to E:\

Tags: wix

I am struggling with Wix installer. During the install, the INSTALLDIR is overridden to a custom folder (not in Program Files). When I uninstall, the INSTALLDIR and the TARGETDIR gets set to E:\ no matter what I do.

How do I fix this? Here are the relevant snippets:

```
    <Property Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION">
        <RegistrySearch Id="GetINSTALLDIRFromRegistry" Root="HKLM"
  Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[ProductCode]" Name="InstallLocation" Type="raw" />
    </Property>

    <SetDirectory Id="TARGETDIR" Value="[ARPINSTALLLOCATION]">Installed</SetDirectory>

    <SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" After="CreateFolders" Sequence="execute">NOT Installed</SetProperty>



  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="WinApp">
            </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

Thanks in advance. I am using Wix Tools 3.10.

**Update 1**

Here are my findings (for now. please correct me as I am still new to Wix)

- Contrary to popular belief, the installer does not seem to set the install folders automatically during uninstall.
- An important exception to the above rule is when the install folders are "well known" folders like ProgramFilesFolder.

So, If you set your directory structure to this:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR">
                <Directory Id="TEST" Name="WinApp" />
            </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
```

You **must** set the INSTALLDIR directory through a property assignment or through a custom action. For example:

```
<Property Id="INSTALLDIR"><![CDATA[C:\mydir1\mydir1]]></Property>
```

If you set INSTALLDIR dynamically through a dialog box, you must read it from the registry or from a file (where you stored it during the install).

**Update 2**

Slightly improved version

```
<SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" Sequence="execute" After="InstallFiles" />

        <Property Id="INSTALLDIR" Secure="yes">
            <RegistrySearch Id="Locate_EXISTINGINSTALLDIR" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[ProductCode]" Name="InstallLocation" Type="directory" />
        </Property>


        <CustomAction Id="SetTARGETDIR"
                                    Directory="TARGETDIR"
                                    Value="[INSTALLDIR]"
                                    Return="check" />


        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <!--this action launches a window to allow the user to choose the folder. don't want 
                    to use standard MSI/Wix dialogs as the functionality is limited
            -->
            <Custom Action='SelectFolderCustomAction' Before='CreateFolders'>NOT Installed</Custom>
            <!--<Custom Action='RegistrationInfoCustomAction' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>-->
            <!--<Custom Action='UninstallCustomAction' Before='RemoveFiles'>Installed AND REMOVE = "ALL"</Custom>-->
            <Custom Action="SetTARGETDIR" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed AND REMOVE = "ALL"</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont understand what you are trying to do above. Why are you reading the install location from the registry?

This is what I do for installing to "D:\Program Files" folder.

```
<Property Id="ROOTDRIVE"><![CDATA[D:\]]></Property>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles" Name="Program Files">
```

Comment: That is only for the uninstall. For the install, they pick it from a custom dialog. I left out that code. If I don't read it, it gets set to E:\.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `SetDirectory` element, it's obsolete. When the product is already installed, **Windows Installer automatically sets the directory properties** to the pathes of the actual installation directories.

The `RegistrySearch` for `ARPINSTALLLOCATION` looks strange too. Normally this property should only be set during first install, which you already do by using the `SetProperty` element.

So the following should be enough:

```
<SetProperty Id="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" After="CreateFolders" Sequence="execute">NOT Installed</SetProperty>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="WinApp"/>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Windows Installer automatically sets the directory properties  ==> That's what I thought. 

I removed the registry stuff as per your answer and it did not uninstall the folder and its contents from the insstall location. I have logging turned on and you can see the results: 


MSI (c) (6C:80) [14:35:52:803]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding TARGETDIR property. Its value is 'E:\'.
MSI (c) (6C:80) [14:35:52:803]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding INSTALLDIR property. Its value is 'E:\'.

Comment: @user3434332 Then `INSTALLDIR` propably is not set correctly during first install. Can you add the code that sets `INSTALLDIR` to your post?

Comment: The install directory is set in a custom action. The user picks the folder. It is set like this in the custom action: session.SetTargetPath("INSTALLDIR", "c:\\company\\product"). If I set it in the Fragment to a well known directory like ProgramFiles, it works fine.